# App crashes after adding parameter do method

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, crash

I've got problem with my simple calculator app:

When I've got method like this

```
public void WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender)
```

it work fine and everything is okay, but when I add float, I mean:

```
public void WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender, float num1)
```

it crashes. I'm not sure what should I give more, becouse I don't do anything with `num1` and app still crashes.

XML(sorry, I'm not native english so a lot of things I named in my language)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_AC"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/AC"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/wynik"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Siedem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/siedem" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Osiem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/osiem"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Dziewiec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dziewiec"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Plus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/plus" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Cztery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cztery" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Piec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/piec" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Szesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/szesc"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Minus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/minus"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Jeden"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/jeden" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Dwa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dwa" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Trzy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/trzy"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Mnozenie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/mnozenie"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Zero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/zero" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Kropka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/kropka" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRownasie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/rownasie" 
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_dzielenie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dzielenie"
            android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

Thank you @beworker and @Raghunandan for answers. I get it. I though adding parameter do method will solve my main problem. My code is (changed to english names)
        switch (bt.getId()){

```
    case R.id.button_AC:
        display.setText("");
        break;

    case R.id.button_Plus:
        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(actualText.toString());
        display.setText("");
        break;

    case R.id.buttonEquals:
        float num2 = Float.parseFloat(actualText.toString());
        float num3 = num1+num2;
        String result  = Float.toString(num3);
        display.setText(wynik);
```

And it says, that in last `case R.id.Equals`, `num1` is not declared.
Thanks:)

Comment: Hard to say without your logcat with the exception. Are you calling `WriteValue` on `onClick` in your xml file ?

Comment: post your xml layout file and relevant activity code.

Comment: sorry for mess. +it doesn't matter which button I click, app still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your layout xml you have a button with the below attributes

```
  android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"
```

So you need to have

```
  public void WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender) // method signature should be like this
  {

  }
```

`android:onClick`

Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, **if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity)**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

If you have this

```
 public void WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender, float num1)
```

your activity does not have `WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender)` which is must since you have `android:onClick="WypiszWartoscPrzycisku"` and when you click the button you get a exception could not find method `WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View)` in Activity.

Edit:

```
    case R.id.button_Plus:
    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(actualText.toString()); // declared and initialized here
    display.setText("");
    break;
```

But you are using it here

```
    case R.id.buttonEquals:
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(actualText.toString());
    float num3 = num1+num2;
```

You need to declare `num1` as a class member

Edit 2:

```
   case R.id.buttonEquals: 
   //  check if you have a button with id R.id.buttonEquals
```

Comment: It's a pitty that I can't give you green check to both of you, but @beworker has got less of them so I gave him. But thank you too! :)

Comment: @tuksiarz check if you have a button with id  `R.id.buttonEquals` in your xml the error is because of that

Comment: everything works fine. Thank you very much!:) I wish I could give you 5 green checks! Greetings:)

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** use first method only. This is the method Android will look for. You can use it with every Button, but then you need to check for sender id to execute appropriate action. Here is an example.

```
public void WypiszWartoscPrzycisku(View sender) {
  if (sender.getId() == R.id.button_Cztery) {
    // execute code for button_Cztery
  } else if (sender.getId() == R.id.button_Dziewiec) {
    // execute code for button_Dziewiec
  } else if (sender.getId() == R.id.button_Plus) {
    // execute code for button_Plus
  }
}
```